# Adding p values/ asterisks from separate list to ggplot barplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to add p-values that I already calculated elsewhere to my ggplot barplot.

```
d <- read.table("DS4 R Analysis.csv",header=TRUE,sep = ",")

d.lmer <- lmer(Corticosterone ~ Group*Sex*CS.NCS + (1|Dam), data = d)
d.anova <- anova(d.lmer)
d.compare <- emmeans(d.lmer, ~ Sex*Group*CS.NCS)
d.pairs <- pairs(d.compare)
d.pairsdf <- data.frame(d.pairs)
```

So I have everything calculated in d.pairs, but I'm not sure how to add it to my barplot

```
corttestplotsummary <- ddply(d, c("CS.NCS", "Sex", "Group"), summarize,
                             N    = sum(!is.na(Corticosterone)),
                             mean = mean(Corticosterone, na.rm = TRUE),
                             sd   = sd(Corticosterone, na.rm = TRUE),
                             se   = sd / sqrt(N))


corttestplotsummaryomit <- na.omit(corttestplotsummary)

corttestunitedcol <- unite(corttestplotsummaryomit, Treatment_Status, c(CS.NCS, Group), remove=TRUE)


x <- c("NCS_Con", "NCS_PNS", "CS_Con", "CS_PNS")

corttestunitedcol %>%
  mutate(Treatment_Status =  factor(Treatment_Status, levels = x)) %>%
  arrange(Treatment_Status)  

p<- ggplot(corttestunitedcol, aes(x=Sex, y=mean, fill=Treatment_Status)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", color="black", 
           position=position_dodge()) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean-sd, ymax=mean+sd), width=.2,
                position=position_dodge(.9)) +
  facet_grid(~Sex, scales = "free_x") +
  theme_bw() + theme( strip.background  = element_blank(),
                      panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "grey80"),
                      panel.border = element_blank(),
                      axis.ticks = element_blank(),
                      panel.grid.minor.x=element_blank(),
                      panel.grid.major.x=element_blank() ) +
  theme(legend.position="bottom") +
  labs(title="Corticosterone",
       y = "mean plasma [corticosterone] (pg/ml)") +
  scale_fill_manual(values =c("#f77f00","#d62828", "#EAE2B7","#fcbf49"),
                    name="Treatment\nStatus",
                    labels=c("- PNS\n- Chronic Stress", "+ PNS\n- Chronic Stress", "- PNS\n+ Chronic Stress", "+ PNS\n+ Chronic Stress"))
```

I've seen https://www.biostars.org/p/377140/ for the label and the if statement and I like that but I just don't know how to pull the label values from a different table.

Cheers!

Comment: It might be a solution but we do not know where is `d`?

Comment: Hi @Duck  is just the dataframe (see edit)

Comment: sorry - updated again. this should make more sense!

Comment: Where is `"DS4 R Analysis.csv"`? It is better if you `dput(d)` and paste the output in the question or `dput(d[sample(nrow(d),40),])`

Answer (score 0):

I would create an additional dataframe with the coordinates for where the asterisks should be on your plot (given x and y coordinates), and then the label that you want them to have (e.g., '*', '', '***').
Given an example dataframe (p_value_labels) of this structure:

```
Sex, y, label
0, 1.5, *
1, 2, **
```

p + geom_text(p_value_labels, aes(x=Sex, y=y, label=label))

It will take some playing around with the y-values to get them to appear on top of your barplots. I'm also making some guesses on the values of your variables as I'm not sure what your x-axis 'Sex' values are, or if you are looking for asterisk labels for your p-values or the numeric values.